# Can't connect to wi-fi

Tags: wireless

I can connect to the internet using ethernet wire, but not using wireless adapter. Why isn't ubuntu recognizing the wireless network interface?

Comment: Can you provide more details about which version of Ubuntu and the wireless device you are using (to help us better answer your question) ?

Answer (score 0):

on my asus netbook [lubuntu], I need to "enable wifi" or the same with Ethernet. Once I did that, Lubuntu is recognizing both types of network. Then, it will show the wireless networks that are available. 
Check it on the right of the desktop, downside.